# Can't find symbol (dot) error when setting font/color

Tags: java

I'm currently working with a book to learn some Java, I'm at one of the beginning programs and copied the code as written down but somehow I get a weird error and simply can't find the error or solution online.

The Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GrussMitProgrammfenster extends JFrame {
    public GrussMitProgrammfenster() {
    super("Hallo");

    Icon icon = new ImageIcon("test.png");
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Viel Erfolg beim", JLabel.CENTER);
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Programmieren mit Java!", JLabel.CENTER);
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel(icon);
    Font schrift = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 24);
    label1.SetFont(schrift);
    label1.SetForeground(Color.RED);
    label2.SetFont(schrift);
    label2.SetForeground(Color.RED);
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.SetBackground(Color.WHITE);
    c.add(label1);
    c.add(label2);
    c.add(label3);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300,250);
    setVisible(true);
}


 public static void main(String[] args){
 new GrussMitProgrammfenster();
 }
}
```

The Errors I'm getting are:

```
GrussMitProgrammfenster.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    label1.SetFont(schrift);
          ^
    symbol:   method SetFont(Font)
  location: variable label1 of type JLabel
    GrussMitProgrammfenster.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    label1.SetForeground(Color.RED);
          ^
  symbol:   method SetForeground(Color)
  location: variable label1 of type JLabel
    GrussMitProgrammfenster.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    label2.SetFont(schrift);
          ^
  symbol:   method SetFont(Font)
  location: variable label2 of type JLabel
GrussMitProgrammfenster.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    label2.SetForeground(Color.RED);
          ^
  symbol:   method SetForeground(Color)
  location: variable label2 of type JLabel
GrussMitProgrammfenster.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    c.SetBackground(Color.WHITE);
     ^
  symbol:   method SetBackground(Color)
  location: variable c of type Container
5 errors
[Finished in 3.2s with exit code 1]
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP could prevent this with an IDE

Answer (score 1):

Should be `label1.setFont` not `label1.SetFont`

Comment: Thank you so much Sir!
How could I not see this, I checked my code so often.

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the method SetBackground() because it doesn't exist, but setBackground() probably does (remember Java is case sensitive!). The output from your compiler or parser is indeed a bit weird as it treats methods as a "symbol".

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget about camelcase! :)
The first letter in the method name is never a capital letter and after that every new word starting letting is capital.
for example:

```
setBackground();
```

or

```
charAt();
```

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining. :)

Answer (score 0):

Method names, by covention, start with small letter.

There's no method named `SetFont()` or `SetForeground` in `JLabel`.

`JLabel` contains `setFont()` and `setForeground`.

So use:

```
label1.setFont ();

label1.setForeground ()

label2.setFont ();

label2.setForeground ()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first letter of the first word of every predefined method is always in lowercase and first letter of every other word after that is in uppercase.
Therefore it should be

`label1.setFont()`

`label1.setForeground()`